# Visual Studio 2010 Formatting

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, ide

I have plenty of experience with Eclipse, and now I'm trying out Visual Studio 2010. I find its formatting somewhat counter-intuitive. Here are some things I'm trying to figure out:

1. Is there a way to select all text and format/indent it properly, like `SHIFT+A SHIFT+I` in Eclipse?
2. Why is it that when I type a line like `if (n == 0) {`, as soon as I type the opening brace, the text cursor is moved to the beginning of the line? Is this some productivity speedup I'm failing to see?
3. When I hit `ENTER` after the aforementioned line, I'd like the closing brace to be put in place automatically for me. How can I do this?

I've looked for hotkey documentation, and it's helped a bit, but this still feels clunky to me.

Answer (score 2):

The Format Document shortcut key combination is `Ctrl K`, `Ctrl D`. Since this command is not supported in C++ ( [Visual Studio 2010: Why aren't key combinations available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179193/visual-studio-2010-why-arent-key-combinations-available)), the workaround for C++ files is to Select All then Format Selection: `Ctrl A`, `Ctrl K`, `Ctrl F`.

On your second and third question, see [Creating and Using IntelliSense Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx). Short version: for `if`, type "if {TAB} {TAB}". Again, this not supported for C++. So if you're in C++, what you're seeing is when you typed typed the `{` on the line after the if, what the editor did was move the `{` to the same indention level as the `if` (not necessarily the beginning of the line), because the coding style it's helping you achieve is

```
if (n == 0)
{
    n = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The formatting commands are by default bound to Ctrl+K Ctrl+??.  Ctrl+K as the first keystoke, followed by another key stroke that determines the specific formatting option.

Look at the *Advanced* submenu of the *Edit* menu.  It will show you that

- "format selection" is Ctrl+k Ctrl+f
- "comment selection" is Ctrl+k Ctrl+c

Comment: Wait, what? I have a default install of VS2010 and mine are: CTRL-E, CTRL-D to format the whole document, CTRL-E, CTRL-F to format selection, CTRL-E, CTRL-C to comment, and CTRL-E, CTRL-U to uncomment. They are the same in VS2008 as well?

Comment: Oh, !@#%.  I think it depends on some questions you are answer the first time you run the app.  I forgot about that... <sigh>

Comment: The first time I ran it, I chose C#, and it says "The key combination (Ctrl+E, Ctrl+D) is not a command."

Comment: So... how can I change those initial settings? And I'll be spending more time with C# than C, so I'd rather leave it on that as the default.

Comment: _Customize_ on the _Tools_ menu lets you change the key bindings however you want.  I think you can even setup differnt bindings for C# than what you use for C++ if you want.

Answer (score 0):

To format a document in visual studio the key combination is: ctrl-k ctrl-d

Comment: I try that, and it says "The key combination (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D) is bound to command (Format Document) which is not currently available."

Comment: @Rosarch, The C++ text editor does not implement that command, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179193/visual-studio-2010-why-arent-key-combinations-available

So the work around for Format Document for C++ files is to Select All then Format Selection: 'Ctrl A', 'Ctrl K', 'Ctrl F'.

Answer (score 0):

just FYI in eclipse it's: ctrl-a  -> ctrl-i
    not shift-a -> shift-i

I'm sure I'm the only one that actually tried that in eclipse.