# Ctrl+k, Ctrl+d not available in Visual Studio 2010 working on C++ project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-formatting

I got used to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> for formatting whole document while in Visual Studio 2010 C# but when I changed C++ I realise that it's no longer available.

To format the document I have to select a piece of code and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>  to format the selected code.

Can someone tell me how to enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> ? Is it possible ?

[image]

Comment: According to this post, the workaround is `Select All then Format Selection: Ctrl A, Ctrl K, Ctrl F`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179193/visual-studio-2010-why-arent-key-combinations-available

Comment: @keyboardP Yes I know, but i was curious if it is possible to get Ctrl+k, Ctrl+d working

Comment: Sorry, I meant to imply that it seems to be the only workaround last time it was asked.

Comment: Sure, you can re-assign any keystroke.  Tools + Customize + Keyboard.  Type "Edit.Format", you can choose what you want from there.

Comment: @HansPassant You can reassign but it will still be unavailable right ?

Comment: Not sure what I need to do to make you actually try this for yourself.

Comment: I'm guessing that the C++ project subsystem doesn't support the "Format Document" command - there's nothing you can do without writing a ton of code - you'd effectively have to create a project subtype of the C++ projects, and then possibly write an extension to automatically convert all standard C++ projects to be your subtype, all for the sake of avoiding learning a new key sequence.

Comment: All behaviors for Formatting Documents are now consistent across all file formats (documents, code files, etc.) in the latest Visual Studio 2017. 

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f5819297-1aa2-498b-a950-948e2f37a1f8/do-default-format-document-hotkeys-work-with-all-other-documents-and-code-files-other-than-the?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> works on code files (C++, C#, VB).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> works on document files (HTML, XML, XAML)

Answer (score 3):

If you are annoyed by the workaround <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> because you end up at the end of your document, just add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to bring the cursor back to where it was before.